# Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found after upgrading PHP from version 7.0 to 7.2

Tags: laravel, apache, laravel-5, soap-client

I upgraded **PHP 7.0** to **7.2** in Ubuntu. After performing an upgrade, I installed Laravel 5.6.

Before the upgrade, class 'SoapClient' is true, but after the upgrade, I encountered

> Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found

I checked `php.ini` in `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` but I didn't see `extension=php_soap.dll` in `php.ini`.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Locate `php.ini` in your **apache** bin folder, I.e `Apache/bin/php.ini`
Remove the `;` from the beginning of `extension=php_soap.dll`
and from `extension=php_openssl.dll` Restart your Apache server

Comment: @HirenGohel , hi. Where is `Apache/bin/php.ini` in ubuntu?

Comment: You told in your question that you don't see extension. The reason is you aren't using the Apache built plugin for PHP. The file paths still work as is listed here to this day (confirmed on my 15.04 VM) See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file/356990

Comment: Also, have you already installed soap? First you need to check it! If you not installed then run this command to install it: `sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap`

Comment: @HirenGohel , I run `sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap` but don't see `extension=php_soap.dll` in `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: Run this 2 command: `sudo service php7.2-fpm restart` and `sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To install SOAP in PHP 7.2 run following in your Ubuntu 16.04 terminal:

1. sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap
2. sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Actually just enough to install `php-soap`. apt should suggest the correct  version

Comment: I restarted `my computer` for set variable!

Answer (score 3):

Look up the following inside your script file

`phpinfo();`

Do the following:

1.Locate `php.ini` in your **apache** bin folder, I.e `Apache/bin/php.ini`.
Remove the `;` from the beginning of `extension=php_soap.dll`

2.Restart your Apache server

**EDIT:**

For your problem you only need to install **soap**.

Run `sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap` to install soap and also run `sudo service php7.2-fpm restart` and `sudo service apache2 restart` and your problem fixed!

Answer (score 1):

First, check by `phpinfo();` This will show you `Soap Client` is it enable or not

If it is disabled Do the following:

1. Locate php.ini in your apache bin folder, I.e Apache/bin/php.ini
2. Remove the ; from the beginning of extension=php_soap.dll
3. Restart your Apache server
4. Look up your phpinfo(); again and check

If `extension=php_soap.dll` not found in your `php.ini` follow below steps

1. sudo apt-get install php7.2-soap
2. sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: hi, Where is `Apache/bin/php.ini` in ubuntu?

Comment: @hadi check this https://askubuntu.com/questions/356968/find-the-correct-php-ini-file/356990

Comment: If you mean `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` ? I not found `extension=php_soap.dll` in `php.ini`.

Comment: @hadi every php.ini has `extension=php_soap.dll` search properly if it is not there add this `extension=php_soap.dll` without ; before line

Comment: I search `extension=php_soap.dll` in `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini` but don't see in `php.ini` :-(

Answer (score 0):

First step you can use this command to check your PHP already enabled "soap"

```
php -m
...
soap <--- It should display
sockets
sodium
...
```

If you don't see "soap", try to reinstall PHP

Remove PHP

```
sudo apt-get purge php8.*
```

Install PHP

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade
sudo apt install php8.2
```

Installation of commonly used modules.

```
sudo apt install php8.2-{bcmath,fpm,xml,mysql,zip,intl,ldap,gd,cli,bz2,curl,mbstring,pgsql,opcache,soap,cgi}
```

last step check "soap" with this command again

```
php -m
```